# How do we hide the SharePoint list name in in modern SharePoint page

Tags: sharepoint-online

[image]

I want to hide the list name from the SharePoint Online modern page.

Answer (score 1):

You could deploy the modern react script web part for your site: https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/master/samples/react-script-editor

Then use some css code to hide the list name in the script web part.

Comment: If my reply helps you, you could accept as answer and upvote it.

Comment: So, in order to hide a line of text in a SharePoint page, I need to be a developer who understands GitHub, SPFx, CSS, and on top of that I need to be a global administrator in my organisation, so I can deploy the web part. Seriously? Microsoft, please just allow us to hide the titles of web parts with a tick box in the UI.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you guys,

I have added a script editor webpart in modern ui. The script editor webpart is built using spfx. Then I used the following css code for hiding "see all" and list name.

```
<style>a[aria-label='See all']{display:none !important;}span.heading{display:none !important;}</style>
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me on the List name.

Answer (score 0):

Create the SPFX extension of type application customizer.And in ApplicationCustomizer class, replace `onInit()` method with below code and insert your list URL

```
@override
public onInit(): Promise<void> {
 if(window.location.href.indexOf("<ListURL>")>-1)
 {
  let titleElement=document.getElementsByClassName('od-ItemContent-title')[0] as HTMLElement;
  titleElement.style.display="none";
 }

 return Promise.resolve();
}
```